# Histogram has spaces between categories / bars

Tags: r, histogram

my histogram has spaces between the categories of this variable.

The variable is Age and has been measured by 5 categories /age groups.

How can I avoid spaces between these categories and make a real histogram so to speak?

My variable age in the dataset:

str(Dataset_Complete_ALL_Variables_$Q4_Age)

[image]
int [1:1137] 4 2 4 3 2 3 3 3 3 2 ..

Comment: Do you need a barplot? Histograms are for continous variables.

Comment: A barplot would be better for distribution of categories

Comment: Thanks. I would like to use this variable in modelling. So does this mean I need to transform this variable to a continuous variable? If so, how do I do it? Many thanks

Comment: Absolutely not, this is a discrete variable and you should treat it as such, transforming it into a continuous variable would be erroneous. Models can take discrete variables as well. You may even think of using it as an ordinal variable, as it appears to be ordered.

Comment: Ok, thanks. However, all my other variables that were measured on a Likert scale from strongly disagree to strongly agree are also displayed like this. I am not understanding why R is doing this because these variables are continuous variables. Do I need to transform them so that R correctly interprets them? Thanks!

Comment: If your age classes don't have a specific meaning, consider even keeping the raw age variable before categorization in your model in order to keep most of the information